# Wagtail rendering of referenced objects in an InlinePanel

Tags: django, wagtail

In my Article pageModel I have an `InlinePanel('technologies', label="Technologies"),` which loads up an `ArticlesPageTechnologies(Orderable)` which is using `PageChooserPanel('technologies', 'rb_tech_portfolio.TechnologiesPage'),`.

This is all working nicely.  But what I want to do is to list links to these referenced pages, but I cannot seem to work out the best way to do this.  The closest I have gotten is with `{% for technology in page.technologies.all %}` but this simply gives me the object which connects the 2 page models, whereas I want the referenced object.  Is this all there ready to use, or do I need to do an extra query in `def_context` to do this?

Thanks,
Dan

---

**Technologies Inline panel**

```
class ArticlesPageTechnologies(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(ArticlesPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='technologies')

    technologies = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('technologies', 'rb_tech_portfolio.TechnologiesPage'),
    ]
```

**Page Model for Articles**

```
class ArticlesPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    thumbnail = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        ImageChooserPanel('thumbnail'),
        InlinePanel('technologies', label="Technologies"),
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # Get all posts
        posts = ArticlesPage.objects.live().public().order_by('-date')[:5]

        context["posts"] = posts
        return context
```

**Articles Page Template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body_class %}template-article{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% comment %}
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.url }}
{% endfor %}
{% endcomment %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-9 col-12-medium">
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
      </header>
      {{ page.body|safe }}
    </section>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col-12-medium">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <section>

      <header>
        <h2>Technologies</h2>
      </header>

      <ul class="link-list">
        {% for technology in page.technologies.all %}
          <li>{{ technology.select_related.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>

    </section>

  </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please show us your actual model definitions, and the template code you're using to render them.

Comment: Not a problem @solarissmoke I have added that to the main description now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
 {% for technology in page.technologies.all %}
     <li>{{ technology.technologies.title }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```

If this looks a little confusing it's because your `ArticlesPageTechnologies` model uses `technologies` in a slightly confusing way. Each `ArticlesPageTechnologies` object links a *single* technology to your page, not multiple ones - the multiplicity is achieved by having several such objects in your `InlinePanel`.

I would suggest you rename the `tehnologies` foreign key to `technology` to reflect this fact. If you do that then your template logic (functionally identical to the above, but with hopefully more understandable variables names) would be:

```
 {% for page_technology in page.technologies.all %}
     <li>{{ page_technology.technology.title }}</li>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed work.  I understand why that works too thanks, but I don't suppose you can suggest a way I could have worked that out myself?  I wonder if there is a template command that could have rendered the page_technology variable showing the objects and variables I could have used.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a template command. I think it's more just a case of becoming familiar with how Django model objects in general work when it comes to foreign/parental key relationships, so that you can follow the relationships in your code.